# SqlAlchemy 'before_insert' event is not triggered with async setup

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I have this setup for an Order class:

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'

    id = Column(pgUUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    number = Column(Integer, default=0) 

    status = Column(Enum(Status), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
```

I'm trying to intercept the 'before_insert' event with this code:

```
@event.listens_for(Order, 'before_insert')
async def before_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    # Use the session linked with the target, ensure it's synchronous
    async_session = AsyncSession(connection)
    
    # Extract the current year from created_at or use the current year if not set
    curr_year = target.created_at.year if target.created_at else datetime.now().year
    
    # Async query to find the current maximum number for the year
    result = await async_session.execute(select(func.max(Order.number)).filter(func.extract('year', Order.created_at) == curr_year))
    max_number = result.scalar_one_or_none()
    
    # Set the number for the current order
    target.number = (max_number or 0) + 1
    
    # Close the async session
    await async_session.close()


engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True, echo=False, pool_size=30, max_overflow=50)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            new_order = Order(**kwargs) # kwargs are some info to create the orders
            session.add(new_order)
            await session.flush()
```

Nevertheless, the event is never triggered. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Can Sqlalchemy events be used in an asynchronous environment?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-events-with-the-asyncio-extension

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Still, I'm not really clear how to map the documentation examples to my specific case. The closest part seems to be "ORM Events on AsyncSession", but I can't see a way to link that to specific events (as before_insert) related to classes like in my case.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10758